# Using fermion-based analog computers to solve NP-hard problems in polynomial time

Tags: fermions, quantum-computer

If the fermion sign problem is an NP-hard problem as [it seems to be proved by this work](https://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0408370), is it possible to take an NP-hard problem, convert it into an equivalent fermionic state evolution problem, prepare the system physically, let it evolve, average over many experiments, and expect the result to converge to the solution of the original problem in a reasonable time? (i.e: less than exponential time)

Comment: There are no proofs in physics. At most one can prove some relationship in the mathematical description of the theory, that doesn't mean anything to nature, though.

Comment: quantum computers are in theory capable of solving a whole class of NP hard problems in polynomial time, however, the reverse is unknown if true, some NP hard problems have not been shown to reach this speed up . (it might be the case that all NP problems can be speeded up by quantum computing, but this has not been demonstrated yet).

Comment: @Wolphramjonny you probably mean quantum computer are capable of solving a whole class of NP hard problem instances, not the problems themselves (which include arbitrary instances). Arbitrary NP problems are reducible to NP-hard problems, so solving any would be sufficient (solving a particular instance however proves nothing).

Comment: Technical nitpick: even if this procedure worked, it could only be used to solve NP problems, not all NP-hard problems.  A solution to an arbitrary *NP* problem can be reduced in polynomial time to the solution to an NP-hard problem, but there exist NP-hard problems that lie outside of NP, so a solution to one NP-hard problem does not give you an efficient solution to every other NP-hard problem, only to every NP problem.

Comment: when I read this article, I understood that it might be an other approach to some cases of uncertainty

Comment: How many experiments do you need to average to get the result to converge to the solution of the original problem? If it's exponentially many, which I believe it is in all the NP-complete cases that have been analyzed, you haven't accomplished anything very useful.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance but it would be helpful for others if somewhere the full form of NP problem is defined.

Comment: To echo @PeterShor, what seems to be missing in the formulation of this question, is the issue of "time complexity", how long it takes to solve the problem. You can in principle use any kind of computer to solve NP-hard problems, it's just that it will take forever unless you have a magic algorithm. The question is substantial only if the real intent is to ask whether 'fermion-based analog computers' can solve NP-hard problems *in polynomial time*.

Comment: @MitchellPorter updated the wording of question to be more precise

Answer (score -1):

Scott Aarson gives examples of problems that might look like enabling such a reduction procedure, but fail in the paper 'NP-complete Problems and Physical Reality'.

> Can NP-complete problems be solved efficiently in the physical universe? I survey proposals
>   including soap bubbles, protein folding, quantum computing, quantum advice, quantum adiabatic
>   algorithms, quantum-mechanical nonlinearities, hidden variables, relativistic time dilation,
>   analog computing, (...)

On classical approaches:

> (...) There are other proposed methods for solving NP-complete problems that involve relaxation to
>   a minimum-energy state, such as spin glasses and protein folding . All of these methods are subject
>   to the same pitfalls of local optima and potentially long relaxation times.

On quantum computing:

> (...) In other words,
>   there is no “brute-force” quantum algorithm to solve NP-complete problems in polynomial time,
>   just as there is no brute-force classical algorithm.

http://www.scottaaronson.com/papers/npcomplete.pdf

Comment: Without the link, this answer contains nothing useful. Please give answers that still give at least some information even if all the links in it rot away.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/139947)

Comment: Do it fast, there is already a delete vote. If your question is already deleted, edit the most important parts of the remote link here, and vote for undelete.

Comment: @heather I would have to copy whole sections of the article, and I'm not qualified enough to provide my own answer (or address this particular problem). I did what I could, however.

Comment: @Real, try putting the answer in your own words as best you can. Or, don't answer the question; instead, provide the link in the comment - there's no shame in that!

Comment: @heather I feel like many answers would be lost if one tried to be absolutely final and correct. I think it's sufficient to try to convey the current relevant knowledge without a definite answer. A "proof" that you can't perform this particular reduction would be great, but that's asking too much, I believe.

Comment: @Real, sure, you don't need to be absolutely final and correct. We simply ask that you try to provide more than just a link as that could end up leading to a faulty location. Just answer what the OP asks, follow a few simple rules, and you'll be fine...I don't see how your objections are relevant.

Comment: @heather I meant his question will probably go unanswered (I can't "Just answer" because answering is too hard), but that reference summarizes what we know about this kind of problem.

Comment: @Real, then either provide it as a comment or further summarize it in your answer so the answer is not just a link. I don't mean to be difficult.